# Migrate unanswered mathematical finance questions to Quant?

Tags: discussion

Many these questions were asked long ago and got no answers. I think they can be answered on Quant Stack. Migrate them there?

https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Basset-pricing%5D+answers%3A0

https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfinance%5D+answers%3A0

https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfinancial-economics%5D+answers%3A0

https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfinancial-markets%5D+answers%3A0

https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bblack-scholes-model%5D+answers%3A0

Answer (score 4):

For most questions this won't be possible, since their older than 60 days and **cannot** be migrated, as this footnote to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232) on migration says:

> <sup>1</sup> After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, *very* rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request.